# When Running PS1 from CMD Out-File cannot access file

Tags: file, powershell, out

When I run the following script in the Powershell ISE or regular powershell window the script runs fine and builds my .SQL query file based on my CSV (Tab Seperated) file.  However If I run the same script from a CMD wrapper it fails.

```
$site1.rawcontent | out-file $source1 ASCII -Width 9999
$site2.rawcontent | out-file $source2 ASCII -Width 9999
$site3.rawcontent | out-file $source3 ASCII -Width 9999
$site4.rawcontent | out-file $source4 ASCII -Width 9999
$site5.rawcontent | out-file $source5 ASCII -Width 9999

$start | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append

$infile = $source1
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($infile)
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $file1;

$counter = 1
try {
    while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
    {
        $myarray=$line -split "\t" | foreach {$_.Trim()}
        if ($myarray[0] -Match "\d{1,4}\.\d{1,3}" -and $myarray[1] -ne {$null}){
$myarray[1] = $myarray[1] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[2] = $myarray[2] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[3] = $myarray[3] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[4] = $myarray[4] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[5] = $myarray[5] -replace "'","''"
"Insert into #terrorist Select convert(varchar(60),replace('OSFI Name: "+$myarray[1],$myarray[2],$myarray[3],$myarray[4],$myarray[5]+,"','''''','''')), no_,branch,name,surname,midname,usual,bname2 " | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append -force
If ($myarray[1] -eq "") {$myarray[1]="~"}
If ($myarray[2] -eq "") {$myarray[2]="~"}
If ($myarray[3] -eq "") {$myarray[3]="~"}
If ($myarray[4] -eq "") {$myarray[4]="~"}
If ($myarray[5] -eq "") {$myarray[5]="~"}
"from cust where cust.surname in ('"+$myarray[2]+,"','"+$myarray[1]+,"','"+$myarray[3]+,"','"+$myarray[4]+,"','"+$myarray[5]+,"') and ( name in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') or 
midname in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') or 
usual in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') or 
bname2 in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') ) 
go" | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append -force

        }   

            #$writer.WriteLine($original);

            #Write-Output  $original;
            #Write-Output  $newlin
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
    $writer.Close()
}

$end1 | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append
```

and it gives the following error..

```
Out-File : The process cannot access the file
'C:\Users\First.Last\Documents\Working\terrorist525.sql' because it is
being used by another process.
At C:\Users\First.Last\Documents\Working\OSFI.PS1:233 char:202
+ ... ual,bname2 " | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append -force
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ou
   tFileCommand
```

The Terrorist525.SQl does not exist before the line `$start | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append`
When i check the SQL files on the information from `$end1 | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append` makes it into the file.

Comment: You don't have the file open while trying to run the script, do you?

Comment: haha definitely not. In fact. if it exists. the first thing the script does is delete it. also the script runs fine when run directly from powershell.

Comment: For a single run, can you try a different filename?

Comment: Yes but the issue is. This script loops and does the above for 5 files. and all 5 have the same issue. again the script works fine from powershell. But the moment i launch it from CMD it wont work. and unfortunately our automation program requires it to be launched from a batch file.

Comment: seems your files are still open for writing.

Comment: Try adding $writer.Close(); to the end of your script

Comment: Also, what else is the batch file doing? What does it's code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$start | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append

$infile = $source1
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($infile)
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $file1;
$writer.Close()
$counter = 1
try {
```

By adding in the $writer.close() in this specific spot it resolved the issue.
Thanks @UnhandledExcepSean